# Replacing the leather on corner parts of a camera

Tags: restoration

I've replaced leathers on cameras before, but I have to replace leather on cameras where the leather went around angles of the cameras.

Note how [on this photo](https://photojottings.com/kodak-no-1a-review/) the leather goes around the angle in a way I cannot reproduce with a flat piece of leather. Or [this one](https://collectiblend.com/Cameras/ICA/Kinamo-35mm.html).

For durability reasons, I would prefer to use leather. I am very curious how these were applied back in the day.

**Has anyone ever replaced the leather on this type of camera body? How would one go about it?**